# Removing/Hiding Null label from x-axis of Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm looking to hide the null label from my chart here. I'm working in Actuate/Opentext designer. I originally needed for there to always be 28 column slots but there isn't always data points for each of those days. If there isn't- the label on the x-axis is showing up as **null**. I'd like to hide this label but can't figure out how. Even changing the color of it to white but I can't get around how to manipulate this label to never show when null. Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsHVO.png) of what I'm trying to remove from my chart and the current code

> beforeGeneration: function(options) { options.xAxis.max = 27
>
> //You can change options here.
>
> options.plotOptions = {
>
> series: {
>
> pointWidth: 25, //size of column
>
> pointPadding: 0.25, //size of padding between each bar
>
> groupPadding: 0 //padding between each value groups in x axis
>
> }
>
> };
>
> },

Answer (score 0):

Use `formatter` function:

```
xAxis: {
  ...,
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return this.value || '';
    }
  }
}
```

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter